# Unique custom attribute Azure ADB2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, custom-attributes, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an azure ADB2C tenant where I'm using built-in, sign-in sign-up policies.

I want to be able to provide users with a custom unique field while sign up.

I am able to add a custom attribute. Is there a way I can add a unique constraint on it such that every user has a unique value for this field while they sign up or are prompted to reenter the value.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom attribute by using built-in for the sign-up policy, the B2C custom attribute only supports three data types: string, boolean(true or false), and int. 
And as I know, the three data types cannot make sure the value to be unique for each user. For the details, please read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr).